# Linear algebra: projection

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $P_2$ together with the inner product $(p(x), q(x)) = p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1) + p(2)q(2)$.  Find the projection of $p(x)=x$ onto the subspace $W=\operatorname{span}\{-x+1,x^{2}+2\}$.

How do you solve this question? I don't get what it means to find the projection of $p(x)=x$ onto $W$. I'm only used to finding the projection of a vector onto $W$.

I did, however, find the orthogonal basis for the subspace being $\{-x+1, x^{2}-2x+4\}$. But I don't know how to apply this to the projection equation.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you have an **orthonormal** basis $\beta=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ for a subspace, then given a vector $u$, the projection onto the subspace of $u$ is $\langle u,v_1\rangle v_1 + \cdots + \langle u,v_k\rangle v_k$. If you have an **orthogonal** basis, then you can turn it into an orthonormal basis by dividing each vector by its norm.

Comment: P.S. "I'm only used to finding the projection of a vector onto $W$". $p(x)$ **is** a vector of the vector space $P_2$.

Comment: I geuss $W$ is a subspace of $P_2$ with orthogonal basis ${−x+1,x^{2}−2x+4}$

Comment: @Erik: Before it was stated what $W$ was (the problem was just edited), the alleged orthogonal basis appeared *ex nihilo*; no way to verify if it was correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf{V}$ is an inner product vector space, and $\mathbf{W}$ is a subspace. If $\beta=\{\mathbf{w}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{w}_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbf{W}$, then the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbf{W}$ can be computed using $\beta$: given a vector $\mathbf{v}$, the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbf{W}$ is
$$\pi_{\mathbf{W}}(\mathbf{v}) = \langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}_1\rangle \mathbf{w}_1+\cdots + \langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}_k\rangle \mathbf{w}_k.$$

If you only have an orthogonal basis, then you need to divide each factor by the square of the norm of the basis vectors. That is, if you have an *orthogonal* basis $\gamma = \{\mathbf{z}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{z}_k\}$, then the projection is given by:
$$\pi_{\mathbf{W}}(\mathbf{v}) = \frac{\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{z}_1\rangle}{\langle \mathbf{z}_1,\mathbf{z}_1\rangle}\mathbf{z}_1 + \cdots + \frac{\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{z}_k\rangle}{\langle\mathbf{z}_k,\mathbf{z}_k\rangle}\mathbf{z}_k.$$

Here, you have a subspace for which you say you already have an orthogonal basis. And you have your vector: $\mathbf{v} = x$. So all you have to do is use the usual formula with these vectors and this inner product. For example, with $\mathbf{v}=x$ and $\mathbf{z}_1 = -x + 1$, we have:
$$\langle x,-x+1\rangle = (0)(-0+1) + (1)(-1+1) + (2)(-2+1) = 0+0-2 = -2.$$

Etc.

Comment: Btw, for $z_2$=$x^{2}-2x+4$, would it be $\frac{11}{41}$($x^{2}$-2x+4}?

Comment: **What** would "it" be? There are so many things to compute, I don't know which one you mean. The projection of $x^2-2x+4$? The normalization of $x^2-2x+4$ onto $\mathbf{W}$? The inner product of $\mathbf{v}$ with $\mathbf{z}_1$? The projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{z}_1)$? Something else? Impossible to tell.

Comment: Sorry for being so ambiguous. I meant the projection of $x^{2}-2x+4$ on W.

Comment: @Ashely: Since $x^2-2x+4$ is *in* $\mathbf{W}$, it's orthogonal projection on $\mathbf{W}$ is itself. So if you really meant that, then I have no idea what you calculated or where $\frac{11}{41}$ came from.

Comment: I guess I mixed it up. The inner product of v with $z_2$=$x^{2}-2x+4$ would be what I was to say.

Comment: @Ashley: You are still mixed up: the inner product of two vectors must be a scalar. What you wrote was a vector. So it mostcertainly cannot be "the inner product of $v$ with $\mathbf{z}_2$". (If you don't know what the thing you are writing down is, then it is hardly surprising you are having so much trouble getting these problems right...)

Comment: I guess I should review this again. What I should say is: is the projection of v onto the vector $z_2$=$x^{2}-2x+4$ $\frac{11}{41}($x^{2}-2x+4}? Or, is the inner product of v and $z_2 \frac{11}{41}$?

Comment: What you've written is the result of computing $$\frac{\langle v,\mathbf{z}_2\rangle}{\langle \mathbf{z}_2,\mathbf{z}_2\rangle}\mathbf{z}_2$$which is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{z}_2)$.

Comment: Alright, thanks